# Ionic - for loop for rect in svg

Tags: ionic-framework

I recently started using IONIC, SoThe problem I have, is for me very difficult to put in words. Please bear with me. 
I'm trying something with svg's within it clickable rectangles. I have to do this multiple times, so instead of putting everything in the HTML file, I thought of using an external JSON file,in it are array's with the x&y values and a string. So that I can keep the HTML file 'clean'.

Anyhow the problem is that, I want to loop the rect element for the clickable rectangels.
This is the Json file with the array in it

```
[
    {"x": "375", "y": "7", "string": "steiger"},
    {"x": "459", "y": "60", "string": "kanaal"},
    {"x": "130", "y": "197", "string": "Westkolk"},
    {"x": "510", "y": "140", "string": "Sluizencomplex"},
    {"x": "492", "y": "237", "string": "wachthaven"},
    {"x": "510", "y": "285", "string": "autosteiger"},
    {"x": "578", "y": "335", "string": "Zwaaikom"},
    {"x": "505", "y": "630", "string": "Scheidingsboei"},
    {"x": "705", "y": "530", "string": "radartoren"},
    {"x": "925", "y": "350", "string": "Kilometerraai"},
    {"x": "880", "y": "295", "string": "schip"},
    {"x": "950", "y": "160", "string": "tunnel"}
]
```

Here is the part with the SVG's, where im trying to loop the rectangles.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1280 700">
<image width="1280" height="700" xlink:href="assets/imgs/maps/samenwerkenopdecorridor/opdracht1.svg">
</image>

<rect *ngFor="let item of coordinaten" x="{{item.x}}" y="7" width="200" height="45" fill="#fff" opacity="0.5" (click)="clickOnArea('Steiger')"
/>
```

I tried to put the *ngFor loop in the rect element, than in the X attribute.

```
 Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:rect'. (" </image> <rect *ngFor="let item of coordinaten" [ERROR ->]x="{{item.x}}" y="7" width="200" height="45" fill="#fff" opacity="0.5" (click)="clickOnArea('Steiger'"): ng:///AppModule/MapPage.html@49:43
```

I got this error. I tried to put a div around de rect element to put the ngFor in the div, but that is also wrong. Please if somebody knows a solution or even if this possible. that would be a great help !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SVG needs special treatment in Angular 2+, read more here: https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html

Now as for your example, you should do something like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1280 700">
<svg:image width="1280" height="700" xlink:href="assets/imgs/maps/samenwerkenopdecorridor/opdracht1.svg">
</svg:image>

<svg:rect *ngFor="let item of coordinaten" [attr.x]="item.x" [attr.y]="7" width="200" height="45" fill="#fff" opacity="0.5" (click)="clickOnArea('Steiger')"
/>
```

Basically anything except for main svg node should have "svg" pre-tag and all the attributes bindings should have [attr.xyz]:
`<svg:path [attr.xyz]=""></svg:path>` etc